# Error inflating SlidingPaneLayout class in AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, slidingpanelayout

**Problem :**

Hey everyone, I have a straightforward issue.

I have used `androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout` in `AndroidX` before, and it worked perfectly fine.

But now, in my another application, `Android-Studio` is giving me an error which basically says it is having problems inflating `SlidingPaneLayout` class.

**What I did :**

- I have checked every dependency and also compared it with my previous app that uses this.
- I rebuilt my project many many times and also cleaned it (`Build > Clean Project`).
- I used previous versions of `material-design` dependency and compiled my project with them, but nothing changed.

**The dependencies I've used :**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Note that I've also tried to switch back to `alpha09` which I used in my other app, but here it did nothing.

**Error :**

I have simply copied and pasted the whole error below.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: afm.scheduler, PID: 5241
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{afm.scheduler/afm.scheduler.ChatActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/afm.scheduler-pdmC1V-CHlc9Wtgy6E_N0A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/afm.scheduler-pdmC1V-CHlc9Wtgy6E_N0A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:610)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at afm.scheduler.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
I/afm.scheduler: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=0 is saved saved_to_disk=0 resolve_classes_delay=8000
Process 5241 terminated.
```

**Goal :**

I just want be able to use `SlidingPaneLayout` in my existing `AndroidX` application.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding "implementation 'androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.1.0'" in your build.gradle file.